# Selecting data from table with conditions in another table

Tags: sql

I'm no expert in SQL but I've heard this type of situation and I just can't wrap my head around it.

Let's say I have 2 tables. One of them has all the information about the objects. The another one contains boolean values for the information that is selected.

**person**:

```
| p_id | firstname | lastname | age |
| 1    | John      | Smith    | 33  |
| 2    | Mickey    | Mouse    | 88  |
...
```

**personinfo**:

```
| i_id | firstname | lastname | age     | p_id |
| 1    | true      | true     | true    | 1    |
| 2    | true      | true     | false   | 2    |
...
```

And now, is it possible to select * from person where p_id = 2 to get only firstname and lastname because age in personinfo table is false? Kinda bad example but anyways, thanks!

Comment: I assume you mean `i_id = 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  A SQL query returns a fixed set of columns, so you would need to return all columns in the result set.  You can, however, set columns to `NULL` based on the second table:

```
select p.p_id,
       (case when pi.firstname then p.firstname end) as firstname,
       (case when pi.lastname then p.lastname end) as lastname,
       (case when pi.age then p.age end) as age
from person p cross join
     personinfo pi
where pi.i_id = 2;
```

A second approach would use `personinfo` to generate dynamic SQL with the appropriate columns and then prepare and execute that statement.

Answer (score 0):

Not a good solution but would do what you are asking for unless you give more information about your problem:

```
If EXISTS(Select 0 FROM PersonInfo Where p_id = 2 and age = false)
BEGIN
Select firstname, lastname from person where p_id = 2
END
ELSE
BEGIN
Select firstname, lastname, age from person where p_id = 2
END
```

A Better solution by creating a temporary table you can get more generalized data not dependent on a particular p_id. Assuming p_id is int:

```
Create Table #Temp
{
    pid int
}

Insert Into #Temp
Select p_id from PersonInfo where age = false

Select firstname, lastname from person where p_id In (Select pid from #Temp)
Select firstname, lastname, age from person where p_id Not In (Select pid from #Temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking a more general question. If there is a false value in the PersonInfo table for a given column, do not return the corresponding value in the Person table. Right? That's what my query does:

```
SELECT p.p_id,
CASE WHEN i.firstname = 'true' THEN p.firstname END AS firstname,
CASE WHEN i.lastname = 'true' THEN p.lastname END AS lastname,
CASE WHEN i.age = 'true' THEN p.age END AS age
FROM Person p LEFT JOIN PersonInfo i
ON p.p_id = i.p_id
```

In your example above, the output gives NULL for Micky Mouse's age.